# Sanitize formatted phone number string by removing two known substrings

Tags: php, string, replace, phone-number, sanitization

I have a value saved in array $phone and want to remove **"Tel. "** and **" - "**. The orignal value of $phone is **"Tel. +47 - 87654321"** and I want it to be **"+4787654321"**.

So far I have made this code:

```
$phone = Tel. +47 - 87654321;

echo "<br />"
. str_replace("Tel. ","",($phone->textContent)
. str_replace(" - ","",$phone->textContent));
```

*This results:*

**+47 - 87654321+4787654321**

How can I avoid printing (echo) the first part of this code? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't concatenate results from both functions because they're returning whole string after changes.

Instead change it in next calls

```
 $string = str_replace("Tel. ", "", $phone->textContent);
 $string = str_replace(" - ", "", $string);
```

or pass array of items to `str_replace()`.

```
 $string = str_replace(array("Tel. ", " - "), "", $phone->textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your intermediate result to a variable. Try:

```
$temp = str_replace("Tel. ","",($phone->textContent);
echo "<br />". str_replace(" - ","",$temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace ("/^(.*)(?=\\+)(.*)$/", "$2", "Tel. +47 - 87654321" )
```

will output:

```
+47 - 87654321
```

Explanation:
it uses regex in order to divide the string into two groups:

1. all the characters that come before the `+` (using lookahead)
2. anything that comes after the `+` including the `+`

and then replace it only with the second group

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this task.  Because the string has a known length and format, you may implement any of the following.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vDd7V))

- Remove non-digit, non-plus characters:

  ```
  echo preg_replace('/[^\d+]+/', '', $phone);
  ```
- Remove the two known, literal strings:

  ```
  echo str_replace(['Tel. ', ' - '], '', $phone);
  ```
- Remove the two known, literal strings:

  ```
  echo strtr($phone, ['Tel. ' => '', ' - ' => '']);
  ```
- Parse the static and dynamic segments, then concatenate:

  ```
  echo implode(sscanf($phone, 'Tel. %s - %s'));
  ```
- Extract substrings by their predictable offsets and length in the formatted string, then concatenate:

  ```
  echo substr($phone, 5, 3) . substr($phone, -8);
  ```